# Identify which submit button was clicked in Django form submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In Django I would like to have a form with 2 submit button options. "save & home" and "save & next".

Any thoughts how I can identify which submit button was clicked in my view?

I'm fairly new to programming/working with forms and appreciate the feedback.

**Form**

```
<form action="{% url 'price_assessment_section_1' component.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

 {{ form.s1_q5_resin_type }}

 <!-- FORM SUBMIT BUTTONS-->

 <button type="submit" >&nbsp;Save&Home</button>

 <button type="submit" >&nbsp;Save&Next</button>

</form> <!-- end form-->
```

**View**

```
@login_required
def price_assessment_section_1(request, component_id):

    component = Component.objects.get(id=component_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PriceAssessmentSection1(request.POST)

                # if "save & home" go to: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal_home'))

                # if "save & next" go to: return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal_sec2'))

    form = PriceAssessmentSection1()
    return render(request, 'portal/price_assessment_section_1.html', {'form': form, 'component':component})
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can give them names. Only clicked buttons send their data with submit. In your template give them appropriate names:

```
<button type="submit" name="save_home" value="Save&Home">&nbsp;Save&Home</button>
<button type="submit" name="save_next" value="Save&Next">&nbsp;Save&Next</button>
```

And in your view in the related section, you can check which button is clicked by checkng its name.

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PriceAssessmentSection1(request.POST)
    if request.POST.get("save_home"):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal_home'))
    elif request.POST.get("save_next"):  # You can use else in here too if there is only 2 submit types.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal_sec2'))
```

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate the feedback

Comment: one thing I had to add to the answer was a "value=1" to each of the buttons.

Comment: It works for <input type="submit"> only. Not for buttons.

Comment: Don't forget to add value to the buttons. It will work like a charm!

Comment: What would be the ideal approach if there are multiple buttons? I do not prefer writing if else ladder for all of them.

Answer (score 7):

In Django 2.x there is a slight change to the view method @FallenAngel's answer

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PriceAssessmentSection1(request.POST)
    # Note change below
    if 'save_home' in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal_home'))
    # Note change below
    elif 'save_next' in request.POST:  # You can use else in here too if there is only 2 submit types.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('portal_sec2'))
```